# How to find members of three.js layers?

Tags: three.js

Having assigned layers to planes used for space planning ("footprints" to allow for required margins around individual models and circulation and enclosures for assemblies) I want to position members to avoid z fighting but closely stacking layers. Is there a simple method to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer; not the best I think.

I collected objects and layers (in cfig.layer) where assigned. After scene is scaled and rendered this does the business.

```
$.each(cfig.layer,function(k,v){
    nr = parseInt(k);
    camera.layers.enable(nr);
    $.each(v,function(k,v){
        obj = scene.getObjectByName(v);
        obj.position.z -= nr;
    });
});
```